# How to hide html source & disable right click and text copy?

Tags: html

The following website has both right click and view source disabled.

http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/sponsor-documents.html

Can anyone shine some light on how this is possible?

Comment: View source disabled? Don't be ridiculous... `:)`

Comment: Press Control+U on that site... I see plenty of source code :)

Comment: Whoa, a 'right-click disabled' script. Flashback from 10-15 years ago!

Comment: Can't rightclick? I'm able to. Oh, NoScript :)

Comment: Whenever a page prevents me from doing thus, I find it my solitary goal to view the source -- makes me happy for a short few moments before reality sucks me back in.

Comment: From the HTML-source of the linked page: "Contents of this webpage can't be seen as they are not meant to be viewed or copied." Yeah, who don't want a website, which contents aren't viewable? And my Opera settings doesn't allow to override the right-click via JavaScript or Plugins…

Comment: Firefox and Chrome can disable the stupid right-click popups, so right-click works as expected. Goodbye, right-click-disable script.

Comment: what about an html encrypter http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter

Comment: Heck, on Firefox I still managed to right click.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> The following website has both right click and view source disabled.

They fooled you. Just scroll down in view-source.

Furthermore, employing such tactics marks you as unprofessional. Don’t do it.

Comment: Disabling right click is a usability attack, but simple tricks like loads of newlines on the beginning or prevent direct download of images with other wrapping images is working for 99% of the users so it's quite effective and doesn't cause any harm. Just because 1% of the population can easily circumvent it doesn't mean it useless.

Comment: @yi_H It’s still useless because you are protecting a worthless asset, at the expense of (1) either decreasing readability of your own code (which you have to maintain) or (2) having entirely useless view logic in your web application. This seems *quite* unprofessional to me. Furthermore, the 1% who can circumvent the “security measure” is the only 1% actually interested in the code in the first place.

Comment: If you think that only that 1% of users want to download images you are seriously misguided.

Comment: @yi_H I think that only 1% (much less, actually) who want to download images would know to look for them in the source code.

Comment: That's why I gave the wrapper image example. But anyway.. I'm not saying hiding content is a good idea (it's up to the owner what he wants) I'm just saying it works.

Answer (score 33):

They do this with some basic javascript, but this does not actually hide your HTML source!  In many browsers you can simply go to view->source on the menu.  Even if you couldn't, it is trivial to simply load up a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), or [packet-sniff the connection](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

**It is impossible to effectively hide the HTML**, JavaScript, or any other resource sent to the client.  Impossible, and isn't all that useful either.

Furthermore, **don't try to disable right-click**, as there are many other items on that menu (such as print!) that people use regularly.

Comment: zapreaction.com they have disable CTRL+U . I am looking how they done it,. No source view nor you can right click.

Comment: @Jai Well for one they're using an iframe to load `/home.php`.  I know this because I can view their source code using the methods I described in my answer.  Just hit F+12 (in Chrome anyway) or otherwise open your developer tools.  Also, any site doing this that is advertising to be a web development/SEO agency is not someone I would ever use.

Answer (score 15):

This code is used for disable the right click events and keyboard shortcuts.

Just try with this code

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 123) {
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }      
 }
```

Comment: it just disables the keyboard shortcuts, nothing else

Answer (score 14):

```
 <body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Use this code to disable right click.

Answer (score 13):

Hiding HTML source isn't really possible. Disabling right-click only frustrates users who wish to do something constructive with your content (copy/paste content or forms, or print, for example).

If you're running a server-side scripting language you could [obfuscate or minify the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600190/php-code-to-obfuscate-html), CSS and Javascript. This will make it harder for someone to copy your code or see how you've achieved certain effects.

Answer (score 13):

It's a horrible thing to do, as everybody else has said, but if you really are intent on doing it, use this code, and put a load of returns at the top of the page's source:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function disableClick(){
        document.onclick=function(event){
          if (event.button == 2) {
            alert('Right Click Message');
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="disableClick()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Man, this is great, it only works for Mozilla though not for Chrome, why?

Comment: It looks like `onclick` isn't fired for a right click in chrome (I think it used to be), change it to `onmousedown` and it will work for chrome

Answer (score 11):

You can still view the source on the website by going to View > Page Source from the toolbar in firefox. Or View > source in IE.

The right-click is disabled via javascript.  The source for the javascript is:

http://www.immihelp.com/common/utils.js

Answer (score 9):

Believe me, no one wants your source as much as you may think they do.  When you decided to develop web pages, you became an open source developer.

It's not possible to disable viewing a pages source.  You can attempt to circumvent unknowledgeable users from seeing the source, but it won't stop anyone who understands how to use menu's or shortcut keys.  Your best bet is to develop your site in a manner that will not be compromised by someone seeing your source.  If you're attempting to hide it for any other reason than to protect your intellectual property, then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You potentially can not prevent user from viewing the HTML source content. The site that you have listed prevents user from right click. but fact is you can still do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> in Firefox to view source!

Comment: `Ctrl+U` works in nearly every browser I've ever saw. Lynx is an exception.

Comment: zapreaction.com they have disable CTRL+U

Comment: @prashant Bhate http://stackoverflow.com/a/40053874/6572922 this link will remove the short keys and right click

Comment: if your content is generated by ajax, the source code shows just empty tag without content, that is how I do it

Comment: if you inject your code with ajax from backend, the source code will show just empty tags, so user can do CTRL+U as many times he wish :)

Answer (score 5):

View source is not disabled in my browser (Chrome).

But they have added a lot of blank lines to the source, so you have to scroll down to view it. Try to scroll down and you will see.

the disabled right click is possible with javascript, but dont do it. Its very irritating for the user.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using jQuery, it is possible to disable rightclick on the whole page like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("html").on("contextmenu",function(){
        return false;});}
```

Comment: This answer assumes jquery is included and available, right? I don't think the answer stands on it's own as is.

Comment: The answer provides working solution. jQuery is JavaScript library easy to use. I assume "contextmenu" has equivalent in JavaScript as well...

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

**ANYTHING** that can be read by the browser can also be read by humans. If you want something hidden, don't send it to the user's browser.

You can add all sorts of gimmicks and tricks to disable right-click and disable `ctrl+U`

All a user has to do is add `view-source:` to the url and they will see the source right away.

Example

`view-source:https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: No, I am pulling my content in php file from DB and via ajax I am injecting it to HTML template. So if the user views the source, he will see only empty HTMl tags without content. If he disables javascript, the content is not injected at all.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot effectively hide your HTML and JavaScript code, even if you encrypt or minify it.

If the code you're trying to hide is really sensitive, it should either be in a protected area of the site, i.e. an area that you can only access via a username and password, or potentially in a client application that isn't exposed via the web.

If you have to expose the application functionality via a web frontend, you could use Silverlight to write the frontend or bits of the frontend. In the old days you could also use ActiveX.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onkeydown = function(e){
        if (e.ctrlKey &&
            (e.keyCode === 67 ||
                e.keyCode === 86 ||
                e.keyCode === 85 ||
                e.keyCode === 117)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have constructed a simple self checking php file, it only allows real loading by humans, and not robots like ( online source code viewer's ) ..

I'm not sure about View Source from Chrome, but it does block access to the html... Not just obfuscation, it uses a bounce back submittance to validate loads.

The short code was still visible in source viewers, so i obfuscated it also...

The page is loaded and bounces back, the bounce gets the real page, not the loader !

```
   // Create A New File called ( lock.php )
```

Copy this into it....

```
<?php 
// PAGE SOURCE GUARD by Elijah Cuff.
if (!hasParam('bounce'))
{
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!-- 
eval(unescape('%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%63%36%36%32%32%30%36%62%32%63%28%73%29%20%7b%0a%09%76%61%72%20%72%20%3d%20%22%22%3b%0a%09%76%61%72%20%74%6d%70%20%3d%20%73%2e%73%70%6c%69%74%28%22%37%36%33%33%31%37%31%22%29%3b%0a%09%73%20%3d%20%75%6e%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%74%6d%70%5b%30%5d%29%3b%0a%09%6b%20%3d%20%75%6e%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%74%6d%70%5b%31%5d%20%2b%20%22%35%37%35%31%36%35%22%29%3b%0a%09%66%6f%72%28%20%76%61%72%20%69%20%3d%20%30%3b%20%69%20%3c%20%73%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%3b%20%69%2b%2b%29%20%7b%0a%09%09%72%20%2b%3d%20%53%74%72%69%6e%67%2e%66%72%6f%6d%43%68%61%72%43%6f%64%65%28%28%70%61%72%73%65%49%6e%74%28%6b%2e%63%68%61%72%41%74%28%69%25%6b%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%29%29%5e%73%2e%63%68%61%72%43%6f%64%65%41%74%28%69%29%29%2b%2d%36%29%3b%0a%09%7d%0a%09%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%72%3b%0a%7d%0a'));
eval(unescape('%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%63%36%36%32%32%30%36%62%32%63%28%27') + '%47%67%7f%76%73%44%15%15%45%69%74%7e%76%23%7a%6e%7f%6f%75%6c%46%2f%73%74%7f%7f%2d%2f%6a%6f%42%28%7e%62%7a%2d%45%15%15%47%66%71%73%7a%7a%20%7f%78%73%6a%45%2d%6b%66%6f%6f%6a%74%2e%23%73%62%72%6d%46%2d%61%70%7e%75%69%6d%2d%21%79%66%74%7e%6e%4a%2d%32%29%44%44%30%68%71%77%7d%7f%41%1a%15%47%34%6c%73%7d%74%41%12%16%47%7c%60%7d%6a%77%7a%42%16%17%23%7c%69%71%6f%7c%78%31%78%6b%7c%5f%68%76%6a%73%7e%7f%27%69%7e%75%69%7c%6a%72%71%2f%29%23%84%1a%15%23%6b%75%6f%7e%74%6e%75%7c%31%68%62%7f%4e%73%6b%75%6e%73%7f%49%79%4a%6f%27%67%28%79%67%7b%67%2a%2a%35%7f%7e%6d%7a%6a%7f%2f%2f%47%16%17%23%27%85%37%23%33%33%33%2e%41%15%15%45%30%78%6f%7d%6a%7f%7f%41%12%10%44%30%69%7f%72%74%417633171%35%39%35%35%31%30%36' + unescape('%27%29%29%3b'));
// -->
</script>
<noscript><i>Javascript required</i></noscript>
";
exit;
}
function hasParam($param)
{
    return isset($_POST[$param]);
}
?>
```

NOW ADD THIS TO THE VERY TOP OF
   EVERY PAGE .. Example....

```
<?php
 // use require for more security...
include('lock.php'); 
?>

<HTML> 
etc.. etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to disable the context menu (right-click), but it's easily overwrittable. For example, in Firefox, go to *Options* -> *Content* and next to the "Enable JavaScript" check box, click *Advanced*. Uncheck the "Disable or replace context menus" option. Now you can right-click all you want.

A simple <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> will view the source. That can never be disabled.

Comment: zapreaction.com they have disable CTRL+U

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 `$(document).bind("contextmenu copy paste cut drag drop ",function(e {`return false;`});`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no full proof way.

But here is some strategy that can be employed to hide source code using "**window.history.pushState()**" and adding `oncontextmenu="return false"` in **body** tag as `attribute` like `<body oncontextmenu="return false">` to disable right click too along with modifying view-source content using "**history.pushState()**".

Detail here - http://freelancer.usercv.com/blog/28/hide-website-source-code-in-view-source-using-stupid-one-line-chinese-hack-code

Answer (score 0):

I think, here, right click is not mentioned, @Jishnu V S.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 123) {
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
     return false;
    }      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, but there is an alternative. It doesn't hide the HTML, but it rather hides JS code. It is better than hiding nothing. If you are using any front-end framework like ReactJS, etc. So, you can actually hide your source code from showing up in the `Sources` tab of the browser.

Follow these easy steps:

1. Create a `.env` file in your project
2. Write `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in the `.env` file
3. Now, deploy the code to Netlify, etc.

Now, `*min.js` files we made rather than original JS files in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

However there is no 100% solution for this, but at least you can make it harder for the users.

In your HTML just place an empty tag, e.g. `<div id="text1"></div>`

Then call a javascript function - send a POST request via ajax to e.g. renderer.php file, which will pull the content from database and return as json response.

Then via `$(#text1).html(textfromphp)` you just put the text to your id on the page.

Plus you disable left/right click on your page via javascript.

So the user can't copy anything from your page, even if the user opens the source code, he will see just empty DIV tag!

You can also disable right click to prevent opening dev tools or F12.

Also the renderer.php file has a session check, so it can't be run standalone if anyone tries it and it also awaits POST request.

If the user disables javascript, the content is not rendered anyway.

The only way to obtain your page content is via Network requests and not everyone can do that.

This is how I protect my content.