# Disable scrolling bar in browser when viewing source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mozilla

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source) I'm curious to know if it is possible to disable scrolling eg: `overflow:hidden` when viewing source code of a web page.

I have read that it is not professional to try to hide the source code of a web page and I agree with that so my question is more about "**what can be done or not**" *and not about* "**should I do it or not**".

Thank you.

Comment: Usually `View source` functionality is provided by an external application (not sure if in Chrome). When I view a source of a page, it's opened with Notepad++, can you imagine a JavaScript code, which could affect a programm run outside of the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **not** hide the source code. But you can try to obfuscate the source to make it harder to reverse engeneer your code. If you use PHP than take a look at the free [Html Encoder for ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/html_encoder.php). But be aware that your visitors can always see the [DOM tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and reverse engeneer the code. And remember: When your visitors disabled javascript they can't access your site.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible and even if it was, it would be pointless, as one could always get the source otherways. E.g. cURLing it.