# How to redirect to another page from view source page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Is it possible to `redirect the page` from `view source page`? Thus, once the user opened my `view source page` it should redirect them to webpage.

Comment: You want to block the user from viewing your source?

Comment: You mean show the source of a different page?

Comment: Thanks for your query. I want to redirect them from my source code page to actual web page.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to hide my source page from users. I know it is not possible but if i redirect them to web page it will help me a bit.

Comment: Quick fix: disable right-click through javascript. But that is easily passed. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source I think you should leave it as it is. No harm in someone viewing your HTML source.

Comment: I have disabled right click also Ctrl C, Ctrl V, Ctrl A, Ctrl U. Now i want to redirect the user from Source page to webpage. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by source-page? Is it 'view source' when your right click or your parent page?

Comment: @shalini: and how do you plan to disable the functionality form a user who can go to `Tools>View Source` or use `firebug`. Such tricks are simply not enough

Comment: @shiva: If i can redirect them from my view source page to my webpage then i need not worry about Tools->View Source menu. I know this is not enough but it will help me at least 1%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No its impossible** to effectively hide the HTML, JavaScript, or any other resource sent to the client.

You can disable the `right click` and `view source` from a normal user, but then it won't stand a chance in case of a more than average user ( and its not even recommend as it might disable functionality like print etc for a normal user)  , as they can always use tools like Firebug.

So the best workaround is still  using a `server-side scripted` web application to generate your HTML, then your business intelligence / process / code is hidden, provided that people do not have access to browse the actual script file on your server.

Answer (score 1):

You cant hide users from viewing your source. There are ways to prevent rightclick on a page. But that too wont help you. There are other ways to view the source.

Hope this helps.