# Oracle Apex hide table structure on Inspect Properties

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

Is there a way to hide the column specs whenever a user access the Inspect Properties?

Apex version: 21.1.6

[image]

Comment: It's not possible - but there are some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source-disable-right-click-and-text-copy), however you'll see in the post that this is not encouraged. What problem are you trying to solve by hiding this from the end user ?

Comment: Due to some SQL Injection security. Would that be also same when hiding the item name on URL?

Comment: SQL Injection ? If your pl/sql code is written properly (bind variables, no contatenated strings) SQL Injection is not an issue. A page item is handled as a bind variable internally and it should be in any custom code - you can't inject sql into a bind variable

Comment: Apex offers plenty of security mechanisms and to avoid tampering in with the url and messing with the DOM and you can code your own checks in the page processes. Discouraging the user from messing with the DOM will give you a false sense of security.